# Sharepoint with external database

Tags: database-connection, external-data

We have a Sharepoint application which uses external database besides content database.we have stored connection string in a list to connect to that external database. everything works fine in a single server farm but when we try to deploy the application in multi server farm, connection string fails for some reason. please help?

Comment: Can you add some details about your environment (use pseudonyms if you don't feel like sharing too much)?

Comment: What do you mean by fails? Is there an error message?  Can it read the connection string but just not connect to the database?  Did you embed creds into the connection string or are you trying to use SSPI/pass through?